# Can't find Mojo definition if packaging maven-plugin is added to pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, mojo

I'm developing a Maven plugin and I'm getting the error: `No mojo definitions found for plugin: my.plugin:my-artifact-id` but ONLY if I have `<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>` added to my pom. If I comment it out or remove it my plugin compiles just fine.

Here's what my project looks like so far:

```
Structure:
- pom.xml
- src
  - main
    - java
      - my.plugin
        - MyMojo.java
        - // some other classes
```

In `MyMojo.java`:

```
@Mojo(name = "mygoal")
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter
    private String someParameter;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        //code here
    }

    // other methods
}
```

In my `pom`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>my-artifact-id-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>my.plugin</groupId>
    <version>0.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>my-artifactid</artifactId>
<name>My Plugin Name</name>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

As far as I understand, it is necessary for this to be included in order for me to import this plugin as a dependency of another project. Is that so?

I have tried using `skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound`, as described in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403669/why-can-maven-not-find-my-custom-mojo). This allows my plugin to compile, but when I try to import it into another project and use it, the other project cannot find the goal `mygoal`.

I would appreciate any guidance on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Create working sample plugin from archetype by command `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=1.2` and compare with own one

Comment: You're missing a dependency on `org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.3.9`. But I'm not sure how it could even compile since `AbstractMojo` is pulled from that dependency. Or maybe you didn't `clean`? Try to run `mvn clean install` and see the output.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried cleaning. I also added `maven-core:3.3.9` as a dependency to my `pom` and got the same error as before. This is weird. It must have compiled before because I was able to execute `mygoal` when I remove `<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>` but then I can't import the plugin into a different project. So I don't know why adding the maven-plugin packaging suddenly means it can't find my mojo.